# Replace text with an Icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-native-popup-menu](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu) to popup a menu when the text Settings is clicked. this is my code

```
 <View>
    <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    <Menu>
      <MenuTrigger text='Settings' />
      <MenuOptions>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Save`)} text='Save' />
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Delete`)} >
          <Text style={{color: 'red'}}>Delete</Text>
        </MenuOption>
        <MenuOption onSelect={() => alert(`Not called`)} disabled={true} text='Disabled' />
      </MenuOptions>
    </Menu>
  </View>
```

this works fine but instead of the text 'Settings' I want to display an Icon from `'react-native-elements'`. Usually I am displaying the Icon with this code

```
<Icon
         name='public' 
         color='#5877'
         onPress={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />
```

Do you have an idea if it's possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for [MenuTrigger](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/doc/api.md#menutrigger) state that if the `text` prop is passed, `children` won't be rendered.

So I'm assuming you can render any React component as a child of the `MenuTrigger`, like this:

```
<MenuTrigger>
  <Icon
    name='public' 
    color='#5877'
  />
</MenuTrigger>
```

Check out the code for the `MenuTrigger` component as well! 
https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu/blob/master/src/MenuTrigger.js#L27